# Working with Thymeleaf Page Layouts

Tags: spring, layout, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying use thymeleaf page layouts in my current spring-boot project.  I add this to my index.html view (place in resources/templates/public):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div th:include="menu :: menu">...</div>
</nav>
```

the view menu.html is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="container" th:fragment="menu">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/}">Project name</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"><a th:href="@{/signin}">Entrar</a></li>
      <li sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"><a th:href="@{/signup}">Cadastro</a></li>
      <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

but when I run the project, I am getting this error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "menu", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (public/index:77)] with root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "menu", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (public/index:77)
```

I have this configuration for thymeleaf in my application.properties file:

```
# THYMELEAF (ThymeleafAutoConfiguration)
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

and I have this configuration class too:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafContext {

  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine  =  new SpringTemplateEngine();

    engine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

    final Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
    dialects.add( new SpringSecurityDialect() );
    engine.setDialects( dialects );

    return engine;
  }

  public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver resolver = new TemplateResolver();
    return resolver;
  }

}
```

what I am missing here?

Comment: Is your menu.html in the same folder as index.html or in a subfolder? In the latter you need to add the subfolder to the th:include. Like subfolder/menu :: menu

Comment: @MystyxMac it's in the same folder.

Comment: Even though they are in the same folder, I think that Thymeleaf start searching from the prefix (in this case /templates/, while the menu.html is in //templates/public. Can you try public/menu :: menu?

Answer (score 0):

The error simply states that there is no `menu.html` where you specified the template files location. I normally prefer XML configuration over properties files. Check if it really should contain the reference for `classpath` on `spring.thymeleaf.prefix`. Below is the configuration I use on my `mvc-dispatcher.xml` to  specify Thymeleaf parameters. As far as I can see your configuration is similar, just not XML:

```
<bean id="templateResolver"  class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
</bean>
```

As you can see I don't refer to `classpath`, just to my `WEB-INF` folder. Try changing to XML and make sure your `menu.html` is not on a sub-folder.

**OBS**: Be careful with specifing a css class on the fragment, Thymeleaf might not load it, since it loads what is inside the fragment, not the actual div that is being referred, Meaning your `class="container"` night simply be ignored. Alternatives are setting the class in the div that includes the fragment or encapsulate the whole fragment on an outer dif which is then named as a fragment.